# Preserve less files after build

Tags: meteor, less

How can I access less files on the server in meteor.

I would like to dynamically generate css from them but when I do `fs.readdirSync('../client')` I only see the compiled css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a file as a raw data on the server side, you should put it in the `/private` folder and use [assets](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets). Files placed in `/client` folder are treated as part of the application and compiled by Meteor, source is no longer available after bundling.

Comment: Thanks! I also just found out that you can mark package files as assets `api.add_files('runner.js', 'server', {isAsset: true});` https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/0.6.5/packages/test-in-console/package.js#L17